# Dart async execution order

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm trying to understand proper execution order of async functions in Dart. Here is a code that puzzles me:

```dart
void main() async {
  print(1);
  f1();
  print(3);
}

void f1() async {
  print(2);
}
```

According to spec first `main()` will be executed then `f1()`. So I expect output:

```
1
3
2
```

However real output is:

```
1
2
3
```

Does it mean `f1()` is executed synchronously?

However if I add `await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);` to `f1()` before `print` the output is as I expect:

```dart
void main() async {
  print(1);
  f1();
  print(3);
}

void f1() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  print(2);
}
```

```
1
3
2
```

Can anyone explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the word `async` does not make a function asynchronous. If you mark a function that is fully synchronous `async`, it will execute as any other synchronous function/code would. When you add the `Future.delayed`, it makes the function actually asynchronous, which puts your `print(2)` in the event queue so that it's executed later than `print(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74195082/200160) there are two quotes from documentation that explain this:

> asynchronous function: An asynchronous function performs **at least one** asynchronous operation and can also perform synchronous operations.

> An async function runs synchronously until the first await keyword.